# Error: Cannot convert parameter 1 from std::string to char*. Confused on why it is giving me this error.

Tags: c++

So once again I need some help with this program for class. Maybe its that I'm tired but I can't seem to find the logic error I'm sure I've made here. Here is my code:

```
#include "Book.h"


using namespace std;

void add (char*, char*, int);
void remove (int&);
void list ();

int Count;

Book Bookshelf [4];

int main ()
{   
    string In;
    string N;
    string A;
    int Y;
    int Num;

    do
    {
        cout << "Bookshelf> ";
        getline(cin, In);

        if (In.compare("add") == 0)
        {
            cout << "Bookshelf> Enter book: ";
            cin >> N >> A >> Y;
            add (N,A,Y);
        }

        else if (In.compare ("remove") == 0)
        {
            cout << "Bookshelf> Select number: ";
            cin >> Num;
            remove (Num);
        }

        else if (In.compare("list") == 0)
        {
            list ();
        }

    } while (cin != "quit");

    return 0;
}

void add (string N, string A, int Y)
{
    if (Bookshelf[4].IsEmpty() == false)
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
    else
    {
        Bookshelf[Count] = Book (N,A,Y);
        Count++;
    }
    cout << "Bookshelf> ";
}
```

The error occurs at the line `add(N,A,Y);` but for the life of me I can't tell why it is saying that. They both look like std::strings to me. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to modify your prototype at the top of your file.

It still says

```
void add (char*, char*, int);
```

It should be

```
void add (string, string, int);
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I can't believe I missed that. Shows what waiting till the last minute to finish does.

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong forward declaration.

```
void add (char*, char*, int);
```

Must be -

```
void add (string, string, int);
```

Also, if the array size is `N`, the accessible indexes are `0` to `N-1`.

```
Book Bookshelf [4];

// .....

if (Bookshelf[4].IsEmpty() == false)  // There is no object at Bookshelf[4]
                                      // Accessible indexes are 0 to 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the declaration match the definition. In the declaration you use `char *` in the definistion you use `string`.

If you want to use C strings see [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). If you want to use strings, remember the '&' to take a reference - saves making a copy. Either way make the prototype and the function signature match.